# How to redirect to login.aspx page off of Global.asax when session ends

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net C# webforms project. I want to redirect to login.aspx page when the session expires. I have the javascript based solutions available on the internet which work fine. However I would like it to work off of global.asax page so that the code will be in one place. I tried to redirect from the Session_End event on the Global.asax but didn't work as no Response and Request object available to this event. There were some references to use Application_AcquireRequestState event as in [Redirecting to another page on Session_end event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565791/redirecting-to-another-page-on-session-end-event) but it didn't work either. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've lived in the .NET world, but as far as I recall, `Session_End` fires on the server without any request triggering it. In other words, when a session expires, `Session_End` will fire. You won't have a Request at that point in time.

Also, if you ever need to move to external sessions, `Session_End` won't fire:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amb/2011/06/03/session_onend-or-session_end-events-in-global-asax-wont-fire-if-you-store-asp-net-sessions-out-of-proc-in-state-server-or-sql-server/

So, you may not want to rely on `Session_End` in the first place.

Since you don't have a Request, you can't do a redirect from the server. You *have* to do it in JavaScript. But if you *really* need the server to "push" the redirect to any connected clients, you could use WebSockets to accomplish this. (I think that would be a bad idea, though.)