# Testing session timeout in C#

Tags: c#, session

I have my session timeout set to 1 in web.config. 
I wanted to check whether session start and end occurs as expected, so I had this in my global.asax.cs-

```
//In Session_Start
Response.Write("<script>alert('session started');</script>");
//In Session_End
Response.Write("<script>alert('session ended');</script>");
```

I get the alert when session starts but not when it ends. When I put breakpoints, I see that the line is executed in Session_End but there is no alert on the screen.

This is my first time working with sessions and even though I was able to test the functions another way, I am curious why it did not show the alert.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you are looking to write to the response and not redirect but have a look at this: [Redirecting to another page on Session_end event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565791/redirecting-to-)
another-page-on-session-end-event

> Session_End is called when the session ends - normally 20 minutes after the last request (for example if browser is inactive or closed).
>    **Since there is no request there is also no response.**

This would strongly suggest that you cannot write to the response... because there isn't one.